# Text to speech library

Tags: c#, text-to-speech

I am new to C# and to programming in General. 
I am wondering if there are any good quality tet to speech libraries available for c#? 
For example, I've used Microsoft library but the speech quality was pretty bad - especially if you compare to http://www.ispeech.org/text.to.speech.demo.php

Could you give any suggestions related to good text to speech libraries, or how to approch this task to produce good text to speech outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did some research on the first part of your question and landed here again: [Microsoft Sam, SAPI alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062625/microsoft-sam-sapi-alternatives)

Comment: I am surprised how limited the choice is!

Comment: You might want to give https://docs.api.audio/docs a little look  - less lines of code and creating audio. No C# SDK right now but there'll be one soon.